# Redirect to login page onajax request

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I am using jsp, jquery, and struts. I have a problem understanding the redirect to login page for ajax request. I tried to see request on browser on XHR tab and it gives me 302 status code in header. I am not able to comprehend how do I redirect.
My approach

1. The application has a function which checks if the user is signed in or not and has function to redirect to login url.
2. Else do some other processing.

How do I come back to same page after login? Is there any way? Also for redirecting on server side I am using Response.redirect(). When I debug the code and response comes on client side the error function in ajax function is executed not success function. Can someone explain how to catch response from server?

```
function buttonpress(param1,param2){
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    data:{
      X:param1,
      Y:param2,
    },
    url:"/application",
    success:function(){
      alert("success message");
    }
    error:function(){
      alert("error message")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: redirecting on Server side inside the Ajax Get call?

Answer (score 2):

```
success:function(){
    //current page URL
    var ref = document.URL;
    location.href = '/login/?ref=' + ref;
}
```

You can use variable "ref" to come back the same page

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you use ajax to call server and receive a redirect response. The browser ***will not redirect***, but will ***automatically retrieve the content at redirected location*** and your `success` function will end up being passed the content from the redirected location. For ajax request, you should not respond with a redirect if the user is not signed in, you should return a `401 Unauthorized` instead and the browser will handle this in your callback. Here are the steps:

- Check if the user is signed in or not
- If the user is not signed in, check the headers for `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` (this indicates an ajax request)
- If found and not authenticated, respond with 401 (for ajax requests) else respond with 302 (for not ajax requests).

And your ajax callback could check if there is a 401 response, set `location.href` to your login page. You could have something like `returnUrl` query string parameter in your login page, if there is you could set it to your current page to redirect to this page after login. Sample code on client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    data:{
      X:param1,
      Y:param2,
    },
    url:"/application",
    success:function()
    {
      alert("success message");
    },
    error:function()
    {
      alert("error message")
    },
    statusCode: {
     401: function() {
      location.href = '/login/?returnUrl=' + document.URL;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

```
        jQuery('#dialog').show(false);
        jQuery('#MsgDel').show(false);
        jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, height: 250, modal: true, width: 250,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function () {

                    var txtValue = $("#<%=txtid.ClientID %>").val();
                    var txtrea = $("#<%=txtreason.ClientID %>").val();
                    if (txtrea == '') {

                    }
                    else {
                        Delete(txtValue, txtrea);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                $('#txtreason').val("");

            }
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#MsgDel').show(false);
        jQuery("#MsgDel").dialog({
            bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, height: 150, modal: true, width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                      --To Reload Page Again After Success Function 
                    window.location.href = "DispatchInstructionList.aspx";
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        });
    }); 

</script>
```